# Rendering django form with django-bootstrap3

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

How can I render a form as table with django-bootstrap3?

I want to do something like this:

```
{% bootstrap_form form.as_table %}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Django Crispy Forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms). Here are the [docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Crispy mainly provides a filter named `|crispy` that will render elegant div based forms. Django Crispy Forms supports several frontend frameworks, such as Twitter Bootstrap (versions 2 and 3), Uni-form and Foundation.